# P4V - remove identic files but with different history from changelist

Tags: perforce, p4v

I shelved files from another branch and unshelved them in the current branch. The problem is that now I have around 1500 files in the changelist and I want to remove the files that are identical between the branches. I've tried with Revert Unchanged Files and it reverts 0 files, but when I individually diff them I get the message that they are identical.
So, how can I remove them from the changelist if they are identical to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think P4V has an equivalent to this, but this is a one-liner at the command line:

```
p4 diff -sr | p4 -x - revert
```

In P4V you can "open command prompt" to get a command prompt that already has the P4 client settings configured correctly; then just copy and paste the above.